# How to PUT a json object with an array using curl

Tags: json, curl

I have a series of data to enter into database.  The user interface to enter the data isn't good for bulk entry, so I'm trying to formulate a command line equivalent.  When I examine the network request of the UI in chrome, I see a PUT request of a json object.  When I try to replicate the request

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/json' -X PUT '{"tags":["tag1","tag2"],"question":"Which band?","answers":[{"id":"a0","answer":"Answer1"},{"id":"a1","answer":"answer2"}]}' http://example.com/service`
```

I get a error

> curl: (3) [globbing] nested braces not supported at pos X

Where X is the character position of first "[".

How can I PUT a json object that includes an array?

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Your command line should have a [-d/--data](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-d) inserted before the string you want to send in the PUT, and you want to set the Content-Type and not Accept.

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X PUT -d '[JSON]' \
     http://example.com/service
```

Using the exact JSON data from the question, the full command line would become:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X PUT \
    -d '{"tags":["tag1","tag2"],
         "question":"Which band?",
         "answers":[{"id":"a0","answer":"Answer1"},
                    {"id":"a1","answer":"answer2"}]}' \
    http://example.com/service
```

*Note: JSON data wrapped only for readability, not valid for `curl` request.*

Comment: -1 because Content-Type (instead of Accept) is the header that should be set in this case.

Comment: For those who are wondering, [JSON] is simply a placeholder for the JSON string. Don't add extra square brackets around your JSON string.

Answer (score 109):

Although the original post had other issues (i.e. the missing "-d"), the error message is more generic.

> curl: (3) [globbing] nested braces not supported at pos X

This is because curly braces {} and square brackets [] are special globbing characters in curl.
To turn this globbing off, use the "**-g**" option.

As an example, the following Solr facet query will fail without the **"-g" to turn off curl globbing**:

`curl -g 'http://localhost:8983/solr/query?json.facet={x:{terms:"myfield"}}'`

Comment: This was the correct solution for me, using `-g` worked as expected. Thanks @Yonik

Comment: My goodness, I've been searching for a solution to my GraphQL curl problem and this helped me. Awesomesauce.

Comment: My issue was with GET and this was the correct answer for me.

Answer (score 40):

It should be mentioned that the `Accept` header tells the server something about what we are accepting back, whereas the relevant header in this context is `Content-Type`

It's often advisable to specify `Content-Type` as `application/json` when sending JSON. For curl the syntax is:

```
-H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

So the complete curl command will be:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X PUT -d '{"tags":["tag1","tag2"],"question":"Which band?","answers":[{"id":"a0","answer":"Answer1"},{"id":"a1","answer":"answer2"}]}' http://example.com/service`
```

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that helped is to use a file of JSON instead of json body text. Based on [How to send file contents as body entity using cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912924/how-to-send-file-contents-as-body-entity-using-curl)

Answer (score 2):

Try using a **single quote** instead of double quotes along with **-g**

Following scenario worked for me

```
curl -g -d '{"collection":[{"NumberOfParcels":1,"Weight":1,"Length":1,"Width":1,"Height":1}]}" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --user test@testmail.com:123456 -X POST  https://yoururl.com
```

WITH

```
curl -g -d "{'collection':[{'NumberOfParcels':1,'Weight':1,'Length':1,'Width':1,'Height':1}]}" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --user test@testmail.com:123456 -X POST  https://yoururl.com
```

This especially ***resolved*** my error curl command error : ***bad url colon is first character***

Comment: Technically JSON must use double quotes.

Comment: @nates Json is a javascript object and therefore it can be used for both string types i.e double or single quotes

Comment: No, JSON only uses double quotes. If your data doesn't use double quotes then it is not JSON, it is probably JavaScript.