# How to send file contents as body entity using cURL

Tags: post, curl

I am using cURL command line utility to send HTTP POST to a web service.  I want to include a file's contents as the body entity of the POST.  I have tried using `-d </path/to/filename>` as well as other variants with type info like `--data </path/to/filename> --data-urlencode </path/to/filename>` etc... the file is always attached.  I need it as the body entity.

Answer (score 547, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the `@filename` syntax, e.g.:

strip new lines

```
curl --data "@/path/to/filename" http://...
```

keep new lines

```
curl --data-binary "@/path/to/filename" http://...
```

---

curl will strip all newlines from the file. If you want to send the file with newlines intact, use `--data-binary` in place of --data

Comment: If you want to be real fancy you can do: `cat file.txt | curl --data "@-" \`(< url.txt )\`` `@-` tells curl to read from stdin. You could also just use the redirect `(< x.txt )` to put in whatever you want. If you're using bash.

Comment: curl will strip all newlines from the file. If you want to send the file with newlines intact, use `--data-binary` in place of `--data`.

Comment: now how would one add login credentials to authorize this request?

Comment: @anon58192932 - That depends upon the security protocol of the server.  If you are using `name:value` pairs, like a username and password, then add the necessary headers that match what the service is expecting:  `--header: "<header_name>:<header_value>"` as a single string.

Answer (score 34):

I know the question has been answered, but in my case I was trying to send the content of a text file to the *Slack Webhook* api and for some reason the above answer did not work. Anywho, this is what finally did the trick for me:

```
curl -X POST -H --silent --data-urlencode "payload={\"text\": \"$(cat file.txt | sed "s/\"/'/g")\"}" https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXX
```

Comment: This one does not convert dots to underscores (. -> _) and keeps newlines. Thanks!

Comment: It's cool, but it doesn't answer the question since the file is exploded on the command line instead of being specified for curl.  I'm also wondering if all of the shell's special characters need to be escaped -- but I don't know enough about that ;)

Comment: For a huge content file, above curl won't work, `curl: argument list too long` in that case accepted answer is life saver `curl --data "@/path/to/filename" http://...`

Answer (score 18):

In my case, `@` caused some sort of encoding problem, I still prefer my old way:

```sh
curl -d "$(cat /path/to/file)" https://example.com
```

Comment: This will cause the "argument list too long" error with large files

Answer (score -5):

curl https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/3300/content -H "Authorization: Bearer $access_token" -F file=@"C:\Crystal Reports\Crystal Reports\mysales.pdf"