# Giving value to parameter from a file to send it through HTTPPOst

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, http-post, httprequest

I have been struggling with Jenkins lately, and I'm stuck because I wanna send some parameters through HTTP Post, and I know how to do it, but the thing is that I am saving a Http request response to a file in my workspace, and then I want to use that file, read it and send the text I saved previously to a new HTTP Request, does anyone have any idea how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: how are you sending your second http request? if curl would work, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15913105/6090676.

Answer (score 0):

Install copy artifacts from another project plugin ( copy artifacts)  add in build steps store the file in your workspace then you can run a shell script to read the desired content from that file .

Comment: Use this in your first job and give target project your second job .. so that your second job/project will be having the output file already there . Then you can write shell script to reqd the content

Comment: If comment is part of your answer edit your answer and put it there.

Answer (score 0):

if curl would work, that would be a simple way to send a file's contents as your POST body. see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15913105/6090676).

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins can work with Jmeter and Jmeter is great tool for handling request and response see [tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/continuous-integration-101-how-run-jmeter-jenkins)