# How to send JSON file as part of request body in CURL POST command

Tags: json, shell, curl, command-line

I am using CURL command line to send HTTP POST to a web service. I want to include a file's contents as a **PART** of the body of the POST command. Is this possible? I know I can send a file as the entire body as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15912924/8571146). But I only want a part of the body to be the content of the file.

For example

```
curl -d '{ "name": "rahul", "speed": "fast", "data": { "number": 1, "letter": "abd", "letter2": "efg"} }' 'http://...'
```

Here I only want `data` as the file's content. Not the entire body. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a variable to contain the file contents:

```
data=$(cat /path/to/file)
```

then substitute it into the JSON:

```
curl -d '{ "name": "rahul", "speed": "fast", "data": "'$data'" }' 'http://...'
```

Comment: It can be any valid path that reaches the file.

Answer (score 1):

You accepted @Barmar's answer, but for anyone reading this, @Barmar switched the double- and single-quotes, which will cause the command to not work as intended.

The following works:

```
data="$(cat filename)" && \
curl -d '{ "name": "rahul", "speed": "fast", "data": "'$data'" }' 'http://...'
```

Notice that the `$data` variable is surrounded by single-quotes first, then double-quotes.

Comment: does it matter if we are enclosing single quotes in double or vice versa ... ? I guess not as long as the other solution is working it does not matter.

Comment: Well, if you have the wrong order the command won't work. I assume the answer was accepted because either the author switched the quotes on accident (therefore, it worked) or the author figured it out and didn't mention it.

I have edited my answer, in order to clarify that @Barmar's answer is wrong

Comment: @WolfSovereign can you edit Barmar's answer so that it is correct?

Comment: Will do, didn't know I could do that tbh, my bad.