# use curl to POST multipart/form-data, file and lots of key-value pairs

Tags: json, forms, curl, post

As part of simulating what the front-end of an application will do while I work on the backend, I have been running various curl commands. Was easy to get just a file to be sent as `Content-Type:application/octet-stream` or just json with `Content-Type:application/json`

I sent json inline with this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}' http://127.0.0.1:8088
```

Pulled the json out of a file and sent it like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H 'Accept: application/json' --data-binary @test.json http://127.0.0.1:8088
```

(any ideas what the 'Accept' does? does not work without it.., solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16621248/4288043))

Sent just a file by itself like this:

```
curl --request POST -H "Content-Type:application/octet-stream"  --data-binary "@photo.jpg"  http://127.0.0.1:8088
```

Multipart with json inline and a picture goes very nicely like this:

```
curl --verbose --request POST --header "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" --form key1=value1  --form upload=@photo.jpg   http://127.0.0.1:8088
```

(solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19148720/4288043))

The trouble starts when I try to pull both the key-value pairs from a file and the photo, or to paste json into the curl command which also uploads a file. Can `curl` be convinced to send `"Content-Type:multipart/form-data"` with key value pairs coming from a file **and** a file attachment coming from a file?

**john.json**

```
{
  "surname" : "Doe",
  "name" : "John",
  "city" : "Manchester",
  "address" : "5 Main Street",
  "hobbies" : ["painting","lawnbowls"]
}
```

and
**john.jpg**

I have tried some things but it just gives me error messages:

Tried inline, pasting in json:

```
$ curl --verbose --request POST --header "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" --data '{"surname" : "Doe","name" : "John","city" : "Manchester","address" : "5 Main Street", "hobbies" : ["painting","lawnbowls"]}'  --form upload=@john.jpg   http://127.0.0.1:8088
Warning: You can only select one HTTP request method! You asked for both POST 
Warning: (-d, --data) and multipart formpost (-F, --form).
```

Then I tried to get them both from a file, but it didn't like that either:

```
$ curl --verbose --request POST --header "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" --form upload@john.json  --form upload=@john.jpg   http://127.0.0.1:8088
Warning: Illegally formatted input field!
curl: option --form: is badly used here
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: In your question, ``--form key1=value1 --form upload=@photo.jpg`` works. So how about this ``--form "upload1=<john.json" --form "upload=@photo.jpg"``? And also in your situation, ``--header "Content-Type:multipart/form-data"`` might be not required. Because I couldn't test this and I'm not sure whether this is the solution for your situation, so I commented here. If this didn't work, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Tanaike that didn't quite work, thought you may have been onto something with the angle bracket, haven't seen that before. Am playing with [the solution in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912924/how-to-send-file-contents-as-body-entity-using-curl#comment48031066_15913105) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47662945/4288043) but haven't worked it out yet.

Comment: I'm really sorry I couldn't help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're on the right track, but taking a look at the `curl` manual page might get you further.

Some key take aways from the `--form` option documentation:

> The difference between @ and < is then that @ makes a  file  get attached in the post as a file upload, while the < makes a text field and just get the contents for that text field from a file.

So for the JSON use `<`, but for the picture use `@`.

I think also you should specify the content type of each section to help the web server know how to parse each section. Although it probably has expectations for each field.

> You can also tell curl what Content-Type to use by using 'type=', in a manner similar to:

```bash
curl -F "web=@index.html;type=text/html" example.com
```

You'll have to look up the MIME types for JSON and jpegs.

And then the final piece to keep in mind: `This option can be used multiple times.`

Most of this is just an echo of what @Tanaike is saying above, but with more explanation from the documentation. I would recommend reading it in further detail.

---

I think the largest complain `curl` has with your command is that each part of the form has the key `upload`. That's sort of ambiguous. Is there one key for JSON and one key for the picture?

It's also really important to know what the webserver expects from each field in the form. There's a wide difference between a file upload and a text field.

Comment: Yes, it is working now. If I change the one "@" to a "<" and then make the two keys different it works. A little bit more fiddling, will post now the command which worked..

Answer (score 5):

With the help from @Breedly and @Tanaike got the following command to work, someone may find it useful one day:

```
curl --verbose --request POST --header "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" --form "upload1=<john.json" --form "upload2=@john.jpg"  http://127.0.0.1:8088
```

It is happy to have `"Content-Type:multipart/form-data"` just once to cover both of them in this case. It really however wants the "<" not a "@" for the json.

The following also works:

```
curl --verbose --request POST  --form "upload1=<john.json;type=application/json" --form "upload2=@john.jpg;type=multipart/form-data"  http://127.0.0.1:8088
```