# Converting postman request to cURL

Tags: curl, postman

I'm trying to convert Postman request to cURL format, but it doesn't work well.
I would like to send a request with form-data includes csv file(with Content-Type url form encoded). It works when I try with Postman, but not works when i try with converted cURL code via Postman.

I attach my postman setting and cURL code converted via Postman.
Should I have to handle something to send a file with cURL?

(english correction also welcome!)
[image]
[image]

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curl's default Content-Type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded so your problem is probably that the data you are POSTing is not actually form data. It might work if you set the content type header properly:

> curl -X POST "your_url" -H "Content-Type: text/csv" -F
> "csvfile=@sample.csv"

Answer (score 1):

Cleared and left the success cases.
Thank you for the answer! And I also referred to below page too!

[use curl to POST multipart/form-data, file and lots of key-value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53724134/use-curl-to-post-multipart-form-data-file-and-lots-of-key-value-pairs)

```
curl -v -X POST 'somewhere' \
--form 'key="value"' \
--form csvfile=@"filePath/sample.csv;type=text/csv"

curl -v -X POST 'somewhere' \
--form 'key=value' \
--form csvfile=@"filePath/sample.csv;type=multipart/form-data"
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop `content-type-header` from the generated code. then you should be good to go.