# How to copy markdown file's content as request body in curl command

Tags: curl, command-line, markdown

I want to call an API that has following request format:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "api-key: API_KEY" \
-d '{"article":
       {"body_markdown":"---\ntitle:A sample article about...\npublished:false\n---\n..."}}' \
<api-url>
```

I want to create the value of `body_markdown` param in one `.md` file. So I create `tes.md` with following content:

```
---
title:A sample article about...
published:false
---

content is here
```

How to copy the content of `tes.md` file to be a curl command line?
I have tried several way but it doesn't work

```
cat tes.md | curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'api-key: <my-key>' --data '@tes.md' <api-url>
```

I also tried something like this

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'api-key: <my-key>' --data '@tes.md' <api-url>
```

this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912924/how-to-send-file-contents-as-body-entity-using-curl) also didn't work.

Where did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First store the contents of the markdown file in a variable. For sending JSON data you should replace newlines with literal `\n` characters:

```sh
markdown=$(sed 's/$/\\n/' test.md | tr -d '\n')
```

Then construct the JSON data string:

```sh
data_string="{\"article\":{\"body_markdown\":\"$markdown\"}}"
```

Then send the data with curl:

```sh
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "api-key: API_KEY" -d "$data_string" http://api.example.com
```