# Recreating a file-based POST request from Django-Rest-Framework test in curl

Tags: django, curl, django-rest-framework

I have a test case using The `test` library from Django. In my test I have the following:

```
class TestLoadCurve(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.test_user = User.objects.create_user('test_user', 'a@b.com', 'test_user')
        self.client.login(username="test_user", password="test_user")

    def test_post_loadcurve_as_xlsx(self):
    response = self.client.post(
        reverse('loadcurves-list'),
        {'file': open("app/tests/loadcurve_files/loadcurve.xlsx", "rb"), "name": "testuploadloadcurve"},
    )
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

And the (simplified) endpoint looks like this:

```
class LoadCurveViewSet(
    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
    mixins.ListModelMixin,
    viewsets.GenericViewSet
):
    ...

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        up_file = request.FILES['file']
        ...
        return Response(status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

This test works. But I want to re-create the `POST` request that it makes using `curl` for some documentation. I have only made it so far:

```
curl --user <myuser>:<mypass> -X POST -H --data-urlencode "payload={\"file\": $(cat app/tests/loadcurve_files/loadcurve.xlsx), \"name\": \"curlloadcurve\"}" http://localhost:5100/loadcurves/
```

Using the debugger I am able to stop the processing at the line `up_file = request.FILES['file']`, at which point I realize that both `request.FILES` and `request.data` are both totally empty. Am I not making the POST request correctly? I was following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50766610/2068931)

Python version is 3.6.9
Django version is 3.1.3

Comment: The issue is not with Django, but your curl request

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm hoping to get help with. I just provided the Django code to establish context.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667797/using-curl-to-upload-post-data-with-files) answer your question? Note the `-F` imples form-encoded data being passed, which should be the case if your `file` is a FileField