# Gitlab Runner, docker executor, deploy from linux container to CIFS share

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci-runner, smb

I have a Gitlab runner that runs all kind of jobs using Docker executors (host is Ubuntu 20, guests are various Linux images). The runner runs containers as unprivileged.

I am stumped on an apparently simple requirement - I need to deploy some artifacts on a Windows machine that exposes the target path as an authenticated share (`\\myserver\myapp`). Nothing more than replacing files on the target with the ones on the source - a simple rsync would be fine.

Gitlab Runner does not allow specifying mounts in the CI config (see https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/28121), so I tried using `mount.cifs`, but I discovered that by default Docker does not allow mounting anything inside the container unless running privileged, which I would like to avoid.

I also tried the suggestion to use `--cap-add` as described at [Mount SMB/CIFS share within a Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989751/mount-smb-cifs-share-within-a-docker-container) but they do not seem to be enough for my host, there are probably other required capabilities and I have no idea how to identify them. Also, this looks just slightly less ugly than running privileged.

Now, I do not strictly need to mount the remote folder - if there were an SMB-aware rsync command for example I would be more than happy to use that. Unfortunately I cannot install or run anything on the Windows machine (no SSH, no SCP, no FTP), I have to use the file share mechanism.

Do you have any idea on how achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`smbclient`](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smbclient.1.html) to copy files from or to a CIFS/Samba/SMB share without creating a mount:

```
smbclient '//myfileserver.domain.tld/sharename' --directory dir1/subdir1 -c 'put /path/to/local/file' -U '<USERNAME>%<PASSWORD>' -W <DOMAIN_WORKGROUP>
```

`put` will copy a local file to the remote share and `get` will copy a remote file from the share to your local system.

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately I cannot install anything on the Windows machine (no SSH, no SCP, no FTP).

You could simply copy an executable (that you can build anywhere else) in [Go](https://go.dev/), listening to a port, ready to receive a file.
This [implementation, for instance: `file-receive.go`](https://github.com/joncrlsn/go-examples/blob/master/file-receive.go). It listens on port 8080 (can be changed) and copies the file content to a local folder.

No installation or setup required: just copy the EXE to the target machine and run it.

From your GitLab runner, you can ['`curl`' send a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15913105/6309) to the remote PC machine, port 8080.

---

Note (Dec. 2023) [`gitlab-org/gitlab-runner` issue 28121](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/28121) ("Allow volume mounts to be configured on a job level for services and build containers") should be delivered for GitLab 16.9 (Feb. 2024).

See [issue 30934: "16.9 Runner Group Iteration Plan"](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/30934).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I wrote "I cannot install anything on the machine" what I really meant is "I can't run any executable on the target machine" - it that weren't the case I would have just copied over rsync or something like that.

I will edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: @LucaLeonardoScorcia OK, I hope someone will propose a better option for your use case.