# Error when executing a request using curl to rest API

Tags: rest, curl, swagger

Please tell me, I run the following request:

```
curl -k -v -X POST 'https://myserver.ru/services/localizationservice/api/Dictionaries/UploadJson' -H 'accept: text/plain' -H  'Content-Type: text/json' -d "{'data': @test.json, 'fileType': json, 'isDelete': false}"
```

and I get the following error:

> {"message":"Validation error: data=Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: @. Path 'data', line 1, position 9./Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: @. Path 'data', line 1, position 9.","exceptionType":"ASE.MD.Platform.Utils.ServiceBase.Exceptions.CustomValidationException, ASE.MD.Platform.Utils.ServiceBase, Version=12.0.21.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null","code":"500","source":"dotnet","inners":[],"extra":"   at ASE.MD.Platform.Utils.ServiceBase.ValidationExt.<>c.<AddCustomValidation>b__0_1(ActionContext c)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ModelStateInvalidFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerAc* Connection #0 to host myserver.ru left intact
> tionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|26_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)","isError":true,"id":"","type":"Error"}

here is the content of the file test.json

```json
{
  "DictionaryCode": "test",
  "Translations": [
    {
      "Key": "Connection",
      "Words": [
        {
          "CultureCode": "en-US",
          "Word": "Connection"
        },
        {
          "CultureCode": "ru-RU",
          "Word": "Связь"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Key": "first+second",
      "Words": [
        {
          "CultureCode": "ru-RU",
          "Word": ""
        },
        {
          "CultureCode": "en-US",
          "Word": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Key": "VersionDiff_DisableReason_KeyAttributesNotSet",
      "Words": [
        {
          "CultureCode": "en-US",
          "Word": "There's nothing you don't need"
        },
        {
          "CultureCode": "ru-RU",
          "Word": "Нет чего не надо"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Can I somehow fix this?

I tried the request

```
curl -k -v -X POST 'https://myserver.ru/services/localizationservice/api/Dictionaries/UploadJson' -H 'accept: text/plain' -H  'Content-Type: text/json' -d "{'data': @test.json, 'fileType': json, 'isDelete': false}"
```

Comment: Duplicate [How to send file contents as body entity using cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912924/how-to-send-file-contents-as-body-entity-using-curl)

Comment: did you design this api?  what are the acceptable mediatypes defined in the api service?  multipart/*?  application/json? You have missing details for us to help you further.