# How to cURL post with JSON parameters?

Tags: json, post, curl

I'm not sure if this is possible, but i am trying to curl a post, but with a json as the parameters, like such:

```
curl -X POST 'https://myserver/action?params={"field1":"something","whatever":10,"description":"body","id":"random","__oh__":{"session":"12345678jhgfdrtyui"}}'
```

however, i keep getting some error `curl: (3) [globbing] nested braces not supported at pos` X

how do i do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172784/how-to-post-json-data-with-curl-from-terminal-commandline-to-test-spring-rest

Comment: @user32342534 i'm not sure i understand correctly - but that other question is talking about sending json inside the body of the request? what if i want to add json as part of the request url parameters? or are you saying that they are the same exactly thing?

Comment: In case of the `Instagram` API it is not the same thing, but mentally for me it is! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data

Comment: `GET` sends the data via the URL, `POST` sends the data in the message body: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSImportExport/latest/DG/SamplePOSTRequest.html. Same encoding style. More: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get.

Answer (score 20):

The curl error is due to braces {} and square brackets [] being special curl globbing characters.  Use the -g option to turn off globbing and you should be fine.

Same issue as this post:
[How to PUT a json object with an array using curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15425446/how-to-put-a-json-object-with-an-array-using-curl/26407256#26407256)

Answer (score 10):

There two ways to approach this.

1. Ensure that your JSON is properly escaped so that it can be sent as a parameter.
2. Set the HTTP header to accept json.

For example:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{"field1":"something","whatever":10,"description":"body","id":"random","__oh__":{"session":"12345678jhgfdrtyui"}}' \
https://example.com/action
```

Comment: Since --data implies a POST method, "-X POST" can be removed from the command line.

Comment: @DanielStenberg true, but explicitness is better IMO.

Comment: Some call it explicit, I call it misleading and error-prone: https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2015/09/11/unnecessary-use-of-curl-x/