# No dialog node condition matched to true in the last dialog round error in watson conversation

Tags: curl, command-line, watson-conversation, watson

I'm trying to use the ibm watson conversation service. Using Curl and the appropriate credentials i'm getting an error and don't understand why. I'm new to this so i need some help

I'm using this command-lines to get the text out of an audio file:

```
curl -X POST -u "{username}":"{password}" --header "Content-Type:application/json"  "{\"input\": {\"text\": \"Hai\"}, \"context\": {\"conversation_id\": \"\", \"system\": {"dialog_stack":[{"dialog_node":"root"}], \"dialog_turn_counter\": 1, \"dialog_request_counter\": 1}}}" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api/v1/workspaces/a9379972-d820-4cdf-b1cb-ad0af898a534/message?version=2017-02-03"
```

and i'm getting this error:

```
curl: (3) [globbing] nested brace in column 11
{"intents":[],"entities":[],"input":{},"output":{"log_messages":[{"level":"warn","msg":"No dialog node matched for the input at a root level."},{"level":"warn","msg":"No dialog node condition matched to true in the last dialog round - context.nodes_visited is empty. Falling back to the root node in the next round."}],"text":[]},"context":{"conversation_id":"4399b894-aefb-41af-9092-cb6594f51cfc","system":{"dialog_stack":[{"dialog_node":"root"}],"dialog_turn_counter":1,"dialog_request_counter":1}}}
```

Comment: Learn a lot more about [JSON](http://json.org/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a warning telling you that no dialog node matched the user input that was submitted to your conversation workspace. This can have multiple causes. Usually this means the dialog flow was not designed optimally (as in ideal case the dialog should always reply something to the user).

Does your conversation workspace contain dialog nodes? Do you have `anything_else` node at the dialog root level as the last node? (this node is used as a fallback node that catches all the inputs your workspace is unable to respond usually with something like "Sorry I did not get that.", etc.)

EDIT: The `curl: (3) [globbing] nested brace in column 11` error is probably caused by this: [How to PUT a json object with an array using curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15425446/how-to-put-a-json-object-with-an-array-using-curl)