# POST data in json array format with curl command in linux

Tags: arrays, json, linux, bash, curl

I am able to POST data with curl in the JSON format with the loop in bash script

```
Current
$(curl -o /dev/null -s  -X POST “${url}" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: ${base}” -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d “{\”data1\”:\”${data1}\”,\”data2\”:\”${data2}\”}”)

[
   {
     "data1": "data1",
     "data2”: "data2”
   },
   {
    "data3”: "data3”,
     "data4”: "data4”
    }
]
```

But my requirement is to achieve below format in JSON array with curl. Please help me to achieve me to append JSON with curl command with every iteration of loop.

```
{“Array":  [
    {
      "data1": "data1",
      "data2”: "data2”
    },
   {
      "data3”: "data3”,
      "data4”: "data4”
    }
]
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15425446/how-to-put-a-json-object-with-an-array-using-curl/15434415

Comment: What are the curly quotes doing in there? This can never work -> `“{\”data1\”:\”${`

Comment: This is the way it works when we want to POST in JSON with curl and it is working for me too.